# typescript - fp ts How to choose a result according of an Option

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, fp-ts

I'm trying to choose between two possible strings according if an Option is Some or None. When option is Some, everything runs correctly, but when it's none, I'm getting a weird error.

```js
import { option } from "fp-ts";
import { pipe } from "fp-ts/function";

pipe(
  option.none, // with option.some("defaultId") works smoothly
  option.foldW(
    () => {
      return "default string";
    },
    (id) => {
      return this.findStringById(id);
    },
  ),
...
```

Said error:

```js
{ message: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_tag')" }
```

I've tried with `option.matchW` also, and `boolean.foldW`, but the first has the same problem and the second doesn't give me access to the inside of `Some`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your code snippet can you include how you're importing `pipe` and `option`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following examples *should* work. I'm using fp-ts 2.11.8. I actually think the issue here may be elsewhere and not related to the option usage. Are you trying to lift this value into another ADT after this call to `pipe`?

```
import { pipe } from 'fp-ts/lib/function';
import * as O from 'fp-ts/lib/Option';
import { option } from 'fp-ts';

// mocked function
const findStringById = id => `finding ${id}`;

pipe(
  O.none,
  O.foldW(
    () => 'default return value',
    (id) => findStringById(id),
  )
); // -> 'default return value'

pipe(
  option.none,
  option.foldW(
    () => 'default return value',
    (id) => findStringById(id),
  )
); // -> 'default return value'

pipe(
  O.some('1234'),
  O.foldW(
    () => 'default return value',
    (id) => findStringById(id),
  )
); // -> 'finding 1234'
```

Comment: Thank you very much, my problem was that I had to wrap the result of the default value in a `taskEither`, and for some reason the type-checking didn't detect that (the method that finds by id actually returns a `taskEither`). So I wrapped it and now it's working, but thanks a lot for your explanation + examples!